# Animated 3d scatterplot in Ruby with ruby_gnuplot

Tags: ruby, gnuplot, data-visualization

Is it possible to create animated 3 dimensional scatterplots in Ruby using the gnuplot gem?

I've had a look through the gem source code, a bunch of examples, and the gnuplot manual, but haven't managed to figure out what to do.

I'm imagining I'll have to fork it and add some do-loop functionality - but before I do that I was wondering if there was a good way of doing it.

Here's an excerpt from my code showing what I have so far.

```
Gnuplot.open do |gp|
  Gnuplot::SPlot.new( gp ) do |plot|
    plot.title 'Orbital Simulation'

    N.times do | i |
      objects.each { | key, object | object.calc_tick(objects.except key) }
      objects.each { | key, object | object.apply_tick }

      x = []
      y = []
      z = []

      objects.each do | key, object |
        x << object.get_x
        y << object.get_y
        z << object.get_z
      end

      plot.data << Gnuplot::DataSet.new( [x, y, z] ) do |ds|
        ds.with = "points"
        ds.notitle
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The method call `Gnuplot::Splot.new(gp) {...}` sends the commands (including splot command and inline data) defined in the given block to the IO object `gp`. Therefore, calling `Gnuplot::Splot.new` successively in loop and insert some waiting behaviour (sleep) after them.

For example, the following code generates the animated 3d scatter plot (actually including only one point).

```
require "gnuplot"

Gnuplot.open do |gp|

  1000.times do |k| ### loop
    Gnuplot::SPlot.new( gp ) do |plot|
      plot.title 'Orbital Simulation'
      plot.xrange "[-2:2]"
      plot.yrange "[-2:2]"
      plot.zrange "[-2:2]"
      x = [Math.sin(k*0.05)]
      y = [Math.cos(k*0.05)]
      z = [Math.sin(k*0.07)]
      plot.data << Gnuplot::DataSet.new( [x, y, z] ) do |ds|
        ds.with = "points ps 2 pt 7"
        ds.notitle
      end
    end
    gp << "\n" ### this is needed to separate line after inline data
    gp.flush   ### flushing popen buffer
    sleep 0.1  ### waiting 
  end
end
```